# Scala matching high order function return value

Tags: scala, function

Hello im trying to use case match with a high order function. if function return true do things same for false. Thank you.

```
def funk(ls:List[Int],f:Int=>Boolean):List[Int]=
{
  f match
  {
    case true => do something
    case false => do somethingelse
  }
}
```

Comment: f match doesnt work because f needs a int not a boolean

Comment: You're not calling the function `f` anywhere. What exactly want the `funk` method to do with the list `ls` and the function `f` and what do you want it to return?

Comment: im trying to make a dropwhile function, teacher's homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a good place to apply "andThen" for partial function:

Here is possibly what you need:

```
def funk(ls: List[Int], f: Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  val z = f.andThen(r => r match {
    case true => List(1, 2) // ..something 
    case false => List(3, 4) // somethingElse
  })
   // function application
  z(5)
}
```

Just dig a bit around PartialFunction's:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to *execute* the function and pass the return value to the `match case` as

```
def funk(ls:List[Int],f:Int=>Boolean):List[Int]=
{
  f(some integer value) match
  {
    case  true => return a list of integers
    case false => return a list of integers
  }
}
```

for example

```
def funk(ls:List[Int],f:Int=>Boolean):List[Int]=
{
  f(ls(0)) match
  {
    case  true => List(1,2)
    case false => List(4,3)
  }
}
```